# openlayers marker's not ordered correctly in z-axis?

Tags: drupal-7, openlayers, markers

I am using drupal openlayers and things are working well except for the marker layering which is all messed up with markers that should be behind instead overlapping those in front. See screenshot.

[image: Markers overlapping]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

edit: So apparently `yOrdering` is the culprit here, but how do I fix this the 'Drupal way' ?

Comment: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/ordering.html, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003349/openlayers-vector-features-z-indexing

Comment: This is a Drupal specific question though. I would expect to be able to get the correct behaviour without hacking the module code... :/

Comment: In that case contact the module owners and ask for a new option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I posted this to the drupal openlayers maintainer, and yes it has been accepted as a bug. Fingers crossed it gets fixed soon.

https//drupal.org/node/2048113